# can I use 2 ivy files?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm creating a build environment for third party developers.  I want to provide them with an ivy.xml which a 3rd party shouldn't change and also a ivy-custom.xml which they should change.

```
<target name="resolve" depends="download-ivy">
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy-custom.xml"/>
</target>
```

This doesn't seem to work, though.  The ivy-custom.xml seems to usurp the original ivy.xml.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider split it into 2 separate modules. The first one is with dependency of your ivy.xml and publish it into your maven repository. (said org="com.abc", name="your-module", version 1.0)

Then you may let your 3rd party developers use ivy-custom.xml that also resolve "your-module" as one of the dependency.

```
<dependency org="com.abc" name="your-module" rev="1.0" transitive="true"/>
```

This assume your developer have access to your repository.

Comment: I was thinking I might have to go that way.  It's not a big deal to do it, so that's probably what I'll do.